# Bizarre Escape Character Question

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlcommand, escaping

I have the following c# code embedded in a literal `<% %>` of a c# asp.net page

```
string commandString = "SELECT tblData.Content " +
                        "FROM tblData " +
                        "WHERE (tblData.ref = N\'%"+myCurrentREF+"%\')";
```

This is breaking my code since it apparently cannot use the `\'` escape character. Why is it so? other escape characters like `\"` are working so why isn't `\'` working?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need to escape a single quote.

Comment: Why do you need to escape ' ? Single quote is not a special character in C# strings.

Comment: FYI: Depending on what other code is going on, you most likely have a SQL injection issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence \" is "working" if you choose " as string terminator.

If you'd use @" as initial string terminator, the sequence \" does *not* escape the quote (but "" does).

So \" is not a "universal" escape sequence, and \' is none.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to escape the single quote. but if you do, you can always try the @ approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
string commandString = "SELECT tblData.Content " +
                    "FROM tblData " +
                    "WHERE (tblData.ref = '%"+myCurrentREF+"%')";
```

This is the correct way, but instead of = did not mean like?, or you string always start with %?